# Comparing coefficients of time series models

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, regression-coefficients

How do I test if two time series' coefficients differ significantly from one another? I feel like this should be pretty simple... should I just use the estimates/standard errors and calculate a Z-score?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Chow Test can be used to test the equivalence of two (or more ) time series models.

Comment: Awesome - this looks like exactly what I need. Do you have any recommendations for packages to use in R?

Comment: Actually this does not appear to be what I am looking for - is the Chow Test only used for looking for structural breaks in time series models? That is all I can seem to find references on. I am wanting to compare the time series of two separate groups, starting from the same time point.

Comment: The Choe test can be used to test for structural breals IF you pre-specify the break point. AUTOBOX , a piece of software that I have helpewd write actually searches for the breakpoint. The null hypothesis you are specifying is that all the coeffiecients are equal . Thid id the null hypothesis of the Chow Test thus it is exactly what you are lookin for at least in my opinion.